# Displaying all users with permissions on a single screen in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, devops, user-management

I'm trying to find a *Plugin* or a *Method* which will display all the jenkins users and their permissions on a single screen .

E.g:

```
Users :  Projects  :  Permission   

a        xyz          read,modify,trigger
```

Is there any plugin available in Jenkins which will help me with above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) and check if this suits your purpose.